# Why can anonymous functions defined with `var` be called in global scope?

Tags: javascript

```
function setupSomeGlobals() {
  // Local variable that ends up within closure
  var num = 666;
  // Store some references to functions as global variables
  var gAlertNumber = function() { console.log(num); }
}

setupSomeGlobals();

gAlertNumber(); //works, WHY?!!

console.log(num); //does not work, GOOD
```

I expected gAlertNumber() to not work outside the setupSomeGlobals() function...

Comment: I dispute that calling gAlertNumber() works in global context like that.

Comment: Are you sure?   What are you running your JS code in?  I just tried it in node and both failed as expected.

Comment: It doesn't. Show _your_ code.

Comment: If you run this in the console, you might have polluted the global namespace through earlier tries.

Comment: gAlertNumber is not defined since it is not it's scope.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, that is what happened. I notice that restarting the browser makes it work as expected.

Comment: Kindly put that in an answer and I will accept. I will probably not be the only n00b who will be mistaken like this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables declared with `var` are **always** going to be local and won't be accessible from the outside.

If you run this in the console, it is more likely that you might have polluted the global namespace through earlier tries. Open a new tab and run the code again.